# Validation group with recaptcha asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, recaptcha

I have a validation group at my contact page with recaptcha.
I know this is a well known problem I followed the instructions but whenever I put validation group to submit button RecaptchaControl_ServerValidate never fires

```
     <asp:CustomValidator ID="RecaptchaValidator" runat="server" 
                OnServerValidate="RecaptchaValidator_ServerValidate" 
                ErrorMessage="Recaptcha input invalid." ValidationGroup="Uyelik" 
                EnableClientScript="False" />

      <recaptcha:Recaptchacontrol ID="RecaptchaControl" theme="custom" runat="server" publickey="6Lfr........."
                customthemewidget="recaptcha_widget" privatekey="6Lfr.........." />

      <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="JOIN GOBLEN SANAT" 
        OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="Uyelik"/>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void RecaptchaValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
      this.RecaptchaControl.Validate();
      e.IsValid = this.RecaptchaControl.IsValid;
    }

 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      if (Page.IsValid && RecaptchaControl.IsValid)
      {
        // do something
      }
      }
      else
      {

        lblResult.Visible = true;
        lblResult.Text = "Incorrect";

      }
    }
```

Note : After 15 hours of try i managed to make it works,

The key is CustomValidator, RequiredFieldValidator, CompareValidator and validationSummary turn all the validators's EnableClientScript to False then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="RecaptchaControl" runat="server" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="RecaptchaValidator" runat="server" OnServerValidate="RecaptchaValidator_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Recaptcha input invalid." ValidationGroup="SomeValidationGroup" />
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void RecaptchaValidator_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    this.RecaptchaControl.Validate();
    e.IsValid = this.RecaptchaControl.IsValid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so you want me to remove public and private keys and custom theme from the recaptcha control. Other than that your code is same as mine.